# Too many values to unpack when creating a data frame from two lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have list `c` and `p` and both have 35300 elements. I try to create a pandas data frame but there´s an error message when I run the code. How Can I fix this?

```
import pandas as pd

e=pd.DataFrame.from_items(['Company',c],['ID',p])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-284-89427a7d8af3> in <module>()
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 
----> 3 e=pd.DataFrame.from_items(['Company',c],['ID',p])

C:\Users\toshiba\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in from_items(cls, items, columns, orient)
   1195         frame : DataFrame
   1196         """
-> 1197         keys, values = zip(*items)
   1198 
   1199         if orient == 'columns':

ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: try `.from_items([['Company',c],['ID',p]])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `c` and `p` are lists, it sounds like you want to define a DataFrame with two columns, `Company` and `ID`:

```
e = pd.DataFrame({'Company':c, 'ID':p})
```

As behzad.nouri's suggests,

```
e = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('Company',c), ('ID',p)])
```

would also work, and unlike my first suggestion, would fix the order of the columns.